# Keep certain columns in a pandas DataFrame, deleting everything else that fall within the column name

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say you have a dataframe that you want to slim down and you have a list of column names you want to keep say

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How do you just get those that fall within the list and just drop everything else in Pandas?

Comment: `output = df.reindex(l,axis=1)` i adviced reindex just in case there s also a possibility that your list may contain column names that aren't present in the original df, id not you can just use `df.loc[:,l]`

Comment: `output = df.loc[:,l]`

Comment: @anky Thought about that, but that assumes that all of `l` is actually in the dataframe. If you look at the phrasing, the question is how to drop all except the ones in `l`, which is a bit different.

Comment: @AmiTavory do you think in that case the second option would suffice? :-)

Comment: @anky Sorry, not sure what you mean by "second option"

Comment: @AmiTavory `df.loc[:, l]`.  Or, `df[l]` as well if a copy will suffice.

Comment: @AmiTavory I meant `df.loc[:,l]` but i appreciate that your answer would eliminate the possibility if some of the list items aren't in the df.columns (upvoted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataframe is `df`, you can use

```
df[[c for c in df.columns if c in l]]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`DataFrame.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[:, l]
```

if not all the column names are in `l` we could use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
df.loc[:, np.isin(df.columns, l)]
```

or [`pd.Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) 
suggested by **@anky** in comments

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.intersection(l,sort=False)]
```

or using `filter`

```
df.loc[:, filter(lambda col: col in l, df.columns)]
```

Comment: @anky is that equivalent to `df.columns & l`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
df = df[df.columns & l]
```

If you actually want to drop them in place instead:

```
df.drop(set(df.columns) - set(l), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass the column list to the dataframe

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = df[l]
```

This will result in a dataframe with columns a, b and c and nothing else.